# Dialog with email addresses

Tags: java, android, xml, dialog, android-alertdialog

I am making an app which needs an authentification.

Users can sign up with their e-mail address.

How can I make a "Continue with" Dialog with all e-mail addresses known by the device?

Like in the picture below:

[image]

When it appears, you have two choices :

- Select one of the suggested e-mails
- Select "None of the above" and write the e-mail yourself

If you "Select one of the suggested e-mails", the app will get back the Username related to the account.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Ok, Where is the question ? I hope you don't think that we will do your  homework?

Comment: I was just aswking if there's a "best practice" to do that. And if something already existing could help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Smart Lock hints to do that: https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/retrieve-hints